# Como actualizar una db sin perder datos en las tablas de estas en Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel, base-de-datos

Cada vez que necesito agregar un campo, otra modificación tengo que ejecutar el comando php artisan migrate:refresh pero al hacerlo el me actualiza la db pero me borra los datos ya insertados. Existe una manera para evitar eso?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

El problema es que `migrate:refresh`, como su nombre lo indica, "refresca" la base de datos, ejecuta todos los métodos `down()` de todas las migraciones previamente ejecutadas y luego corre todas las migraciones `up()` existentes.

---

Para agregar o borrar un campo o hacer alguna otra modificación a la base de datos (incluso borrar tablas, índices, etc), solo debes crear una nueva migración:

```
php artisan make:migration agregar_campo_x
```

En el archivo respectivo de la migración puedes agregar un campo a una tabla existente así:

```
Schema::table('usuarios', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->string('direccion');
});
```

Cuando tengas lista tu migración, la ejecutas sin parámetros adicionales:

```
php artisan migrate
```

Comment: Ah ya veo, ahora estoy mas tranquilo, con solo crear una nueva migracion no se borrarian los datos de esa tabla. Gracias por tu respuesta